# How do I get Google Maps "Places API" to return ZIP code information?

Tags: java, google-maps-api-3

How do I get Google Maps "Places API" to return ZIP code information?   In all the examples I find on the internet, none of them show results returning that contain a ZIP code.  Is there a trick to this or is it not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like it's returning a "postal code" (4 digits for some reason) in the `address_component` section:

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#PlaceDetailsRequests

However, I think what you're looking for is the Google Geocoding API:

> Geocoding is the process of converting addresses (like "1600
>   Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates
>   (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739), which you can use
>   to place markers or position the map. The Google Geocoding API
>   provides a direct way to access a geocoder via an HTTP request. Additionally, the service 
>   allows you to perform the converse operation (turning coordinates into
>   addresses); this process is known as "reverse geocoding."

You can see in the JSON and XML responses a 5-digit postal code:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#JSON

Comment: No, I am not trying to Geocode.  I am trying to "map search"... thats all.  While the examples show postal code returning, I don't see them returning in a real world scenerio.

Comment: @djangofan What I was thinking is that you will [almost] always get the latitude/longitude coordinates from a map search, so you could use that with a reverse geocode to obtain a zip code.

Comment: I think what you mean by reverse geocode is just to do a "geocode address search" right?  I'll try that.

Comment: "The [GeoCoding] service allows you to perform the converse operation (turning coordinates into addresses); this process is known as 'reverse geocoding.'"

Comment: I figured out the answer by using "Google Text Search in the Places API" , which returns zip code with place information (without the prerequisite of needing the geo coordinates).

Answer (score -3):

check with:
place.AddressDetails.Country.AdministrativeArea.SubAdministrativeArea.Locality.PostalCode.PostalCodeNumber