# Google Maps API not returning some postal codes (French cities)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-api

I have an autocomplete field on my rails app, which is **not returning the postal_code for some French cities**, whereas **they actually DO exist** (and since all cities in France have a unique postal code).

For example, in the link below, if you search for "Saint-Malo, France", no postal code is returned. Although when you search "Saint-Malo, France" in googlemaps.com the city is clearly identified :

http://lewagon.github.io/google-place-autocomplete/

Is there a **smart way to work around this problem** and be sure that when my visitors select a city in the autocomplete input field, a postal code will be found ?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805704/how-do-i-get-google-maps-places-api-to-return-zip-code-information

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can return another postal code that also belongs to the city. Not a solution but it might work..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).